# circular import references from zope schemas

Tags: python, schema, plone, zope, circular-reference

i'm having a problem very similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417571/defining-circular-references-using-zope-schema), but my attempts to apply these previous answers isn't going thru and it was suggested i start it as a new question:

in the code below i define a couple of getChoices() functions that i thought would defer the circular refs, but no!? what's wrong here, please?

```
# ns.content/ns/content/foo.py
from zope import schema
from plone.directives import form
from z3c.relationfield.schema import Relation, RelationChoice
from plone.formwidget.contenttree import ObjPathSourceBinder

class IFoo(form.Schema):

    def getBarChoices():
        # avoiding circular refs...
        from bar import IBar
        return ObjPathSourceBinder(object_provides=IBar.__identifier__)

    barChoices = getBarChoices()
    form.widget(bar=AutocompleteFieldWidget)
    bar = Relation(source= barChoices,required=False)

# ns.content/ns/content/bar.py
from zope import schema
from plone.directives import form
from z3c.relationfield.schema import Relation, RelationChoice
from plone.formwidget.contenttree import ObjPathSourceBinder

class IBar(form.Schema):

    def getFooChoices():
        # avoiding circular refs...
        from foo import IFoo
        return ObjPathSourceBinder(object_provides=IFoo.__identifier__)

    fooChoices = getFooChoices()
    form.widget(foo=AutocompleteFieldWidget)
    foo = Relation(source= fooChoices,required=False)

resultingError = """
  File ".../buildout-cache/eggs/martian-0.11.3-py2.7.egg/martian/scan.py", line 217, in resolve
    __import__(used)
  File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/bar.py", line 32, in <module>
    class IBar(form.Schema):
  File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/bar.py", line 48, in IBar
    fooChoices = getFooChoices()
  File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/bar.py", line 38, in getFooChoices
    from ns.content.foo import IFoo
  File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/foo.py", line 33, in <module>
    class IFoo(form.Schema):
  File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/foo.py", line 73, in IFoo
    barChoices = getBarChoices()
  File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/foo.py", line 39, in getBarChoices
    from ns.content.bar import IBar
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File ".../zeocluster/parts/client1/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File ".../buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.2.0.1-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 102.4-106.10
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File ".../zeocluster/src/ns.content/ns/content/configure.zcml", line 18.2-18.27
    ImportError: cannot import name IBar
"""
```

Comment: This is Plone, right? Could you please add the imports you're using in foo.py and bar.py?

Comment: I had two errors in the code in the first version of my answer, please see my updated version. (Use directlyProvides instead of implements, and don't accidentally make `source` a schema field)

Comment: BTW, you also need to use `RelationChoice` instead of `Relation`. Only `RelationChoice` uses a vocabulary source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `getBarChoices()` at definition time, when defining the class `IFoo`. So `from bar import IBar` will be executed while parsing `foo.py` leading to the circular import.

As far as I see it, you have basically two choices:

**1) Use a string as identifier for object_provides.**

You're doing that already anyway by using `IFoo.__identifier__`, but if you make it static instead of dynamic that will eliminate your circular dependencies:

```
source = ObjPathSourceBinder(object_provides='ns.content.bar.IBar')
bar = Relation(source=source,required=False)
```

No need to import `IBar` in `foo.py`. This has the obvious disadvantage that the location of `IBar` is now hardcoded in your code, so whenever you change the name or location of `IBar` you'll need to update its dotted name in `foo.py`.

**2) Marker interfaces**

The other alternative would be to let `IFoo` and `IBar` implement marker interfaces that you keep in a third file, `ns/content/interfaces.py` for example. That way you could do something along the lines of

**interfaces.py**

```
from zope.interface import Interface

class IBarMarker(Interface):
    """Marker interface for IBar objects.
    """

class IFooMarker(Interface):
    """Marker interface for IFoo objects.
    """
```

**foo.py**

```
from zope.interface import directlyProvides
from plone.directives import form
from plone.formwidget.contenttree import ObjPathSourceBinder
from plone.formwidget.autocomplete import AutocompleteFieldWidget
from z3c.relationfield.schema import RelationChoice

from ns.content.interfaces import IBarMarker
from ns.content.interfaces import IFooMarker


class IFoo(form.Schema):
    directlyProvides(IFooMarker)

    form.widget(bar=AutocompleteFieldWidget)
    bar = RelationChoice(source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
                            object_provides=IBarMarker.__identifier__),
                         required=False)
```

**bar.py**

```
class IBar(form.Schema):
    directlyProvides(IBarMarker)

    form.widget(foo=AutocompleteFieldWidget)
    foo = RelationChoice(source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
                            object_provides=IFooMarker.__identifier__),
                         required=False)
```

Comment: your first comment "You're calling getBarChoices() at definition time, when defining the class IFoo" made me move these functions outside the class definition, but this didn't help.

Comment: @rikb You might have moved the definition of the functions out, but you're still _calling_ them during the class definitions. That's where the circular import happens.

Comment: (following Martin Aspeli, _Pro Plone4 Development_ p. 337) since i want to avoid a separate interfaces module, i went with your static string solution; it works!  thanks Lucas