# Plone content type relation cycle

Tags: plone, content-type

I want two content type like:

```python
# in content_type_a.py
from content_type_b import IContentTypeB
class IContentTypeA(model.Schema):
    content_type_bs = RelationList(
        default=[],
        value_type=RelationChoice(
            source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
                object_provides=IContentTypeB.__identifier__
            ),
        ),
        required=False,
    )

# in content_type_b.py
from content_type_a import IContentTypeA
class IContentTypeB(model.Schema):
    content_type_as = RelationList(
        default=[],
        value_type=RelationChoice(
            source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
                object_provides=IContentTypeA.__identifier__
            ),
        ),
        required=False,
    )
```

But have error: ImportError: cannot import name IContentTypeA

any idea for me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: The traceback should be clear. You don't have a `IContentTypeA`class (interface) in your `content_type_b`. The naming is a little bit confusing. Please post the code of both modules.

Comment: I found my problem and solution at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286692/circular-import-references-from-zope-schemas

Thank you!